# prove $n_i \ge i$ by induction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$n_i$ is an strictly increasing monotone sequence, and $i \in N$. $n_i \in N$

$P(1) : n_1 \ge 1$

Suppose $P(k) : n_k \ge k$

Then, $P(k+1) : n_{k+1} \ge n_k$. I am stuck in here.

Could you give some hint??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there any property for $n_{i}$. If not $n_{2}=1.5$ and $n_{k}=n_{k-1}+1$ is monotone and increasing but does not satisfy your required condition.

Comment: Monotone increasing means $n_{k+1} > n_k$ (strict inequality!). Also, as a hint, it is certainly true of whole numbers that if $a>b$, then $a \geq b+1$...

Comment: Problem is not clear.

Comment: Patrick, sorry I edited it

Comment: $n_{k+1}> n_{k}\geq k$, so $n_{k+1}>k$. as $n_{k+1}$ is a natural number then $n_{k+1}\geq k+1$

Comment: it does make sense. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

From $$P(k) : n_k \ge k$$

You need to prove that  $$P(k+1) : n_{k+1} \ge k+1$$

Note that $$n_{k+1} > n_k \ge k \implies n_{k+1} > k$$

Since $n_{k+1}$ is an integer, $$n_{k+1} > k \implies n_{k+1} \ge k+1$$

Thus  $$P(k+1) : n_{k+1} \ge k+1$$

Comment: edit: $ n_{k+1} > n_k \ge k \implies n_{k+1} > k$